# Redirecting output from a bash command into a script

Tags: bash, shell, qr-code, zbar

I'm trying to do some stuff with QR codes and a found a library called ZBar. Once installed it comes with a bash command called zbarcam which reads from a camera and continuously prints out whenever it scans and decodes a QR code (it prints out the decoded value of the QR). I want to, instead of printing the output, take the output and give it as an input to another script so I can do some things with it. TL;DR how can a continuously capture the output from zbarcam and pass it to my script as an input.

Answer (score 0):

Is it from [zbar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/)?

They have an example in their manpage:

> Scan for barcodes using the second video device and pipe the resulting data through a script that searches for each code in a database and does something useful with them:
>
> zbarcam /dev/video1 | upcrpc.py
>
> The upcrpc.py example script included in the examples/ subdirectory of the distribution will make an XMLRPC call to a popular internet UPC database and print the product description if found.